# Read two bytes from binary stream

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file with binary data which I need to analyze.
The data I am looking for is separated in two-byte long parts.

I tried using file.read(2), but this is very slow for a 1.5 MB file.

```
file = open('data', 'rb')
data = file.read().hex()
```

is what I currently use to load the data in a `b''` object and convert it to hex data for further processing.

Now I need to read always two bytes from this string, how can I achieve this?

F.e.:

```
...c429c429c429c429...

should be processed as

c429, c429, c429, c429
```

Where 'c4' equals 1 bytes.

Comment: `c4` equals 1 byte doesn't it?

Comment: @blhsing yes, this was a typo, sorry.

Comment: It sounds like you need to regroup the incoming iterable into two-part chunks. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915170/split-a-generator-iterable-every-n-items-in-python-splitevery) has a few different ways of doing that, so you can choose one that matches your style.