# Python - Go through only 5 pages at one time in PyMuPdf Fitz

Tags: python, pymupdf

- I want to iterate through the last 5 pages of a PDF in `PyMuPdf`, and ask the user if he wants to iterate through more 5 pages.
- I came across `reversed` method of `PyMuPdf`, but that doesn't take the parameter of limiting it to only 5 pages.
- Example, total 20 pages in a PDF. First process Page no. 16 to 20 in reverse order i.e. `20-19-18-17-16` and if the user enters Yes to process another 5 pages then process `15-14-13-12-11` and so on.
- `doc.pages(start, stop, step)` this method can be used for iterating through particular number of pages, but then I have to manually calculate the start and end, and do which is not a good practice.

Comment: Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22919323/257027) answer that uses `itertools` with `islice` and `takewhile`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the `Document.pages()` iterator.
Simply iterate over `Document.pages(-5)` which will yield the last 5 pages.

Answer (score 1):

Use `doc.page_count`

1. Create a **list** of the page numbers, in your case it is the **last 5 pages**.
2. Use the syntax `last_pages=list(range(doc.page_count-5,doc.page_count))`
3. **Iterate** through the list representing the page numbers.